# Get value from input box with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form and want to pass a value from it to my javascript - and use this value to create a javascript variable.

Im a newbie at javascript and cant get it to work.

Here is my code:

```
<input id="bartype" name="bartype" type="text" value="<?php echo $bartype; ?>" style="display:none" />
```

I want to grab the value and in my javascript create this var:

```
var type = $('#bartype');
var targetUrl = 'listing.php?page=$'+type;
```

How do I do this?

Thanks a lot

Comment: google "jQuery value" and first result is your answer. Why don't try manual first?

Comment: JavaScript works client-side; the PHP is irrelevant, please -when asking JavaScript questions- post the client-side (relevant) HTML, not the server-side script that generates it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var type = $('#bartype').val();
var targetUrl = 'listing.php?page='+type;
```

Use google developer tools or firebug to debug javascript

```
console.log($('#bartype'))
```

You should go trough some tutorials:

http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials

Comment: Actually its not working as I want.. When I inspect the HTML the form part looks right:

    <input id="bartype" name="bartype" type="text" value="vip" style="display:none">

But the javascript is not getting the type. If I hardcode the type it works:

var targetUrl = 'listing.php?page=vip';

But not this: var targetUrl = 'listing.php?page='+type;

Any ideas?

Comment: $(function() { var type = $('#bartype').val(); var targetUrl = 'listing.php?page='+type; console.log($('#bartype').length)
 })

Comment: You should wrap all Your jQuery code inside this code $(function() {        }) it is shortcut for http://api.jquery.com/ready/